# Как разместить видео и pdf файл по центру страницы?

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

```html
<video src="else/replicationDna.mp4" controls width="500" height="300"></video>

<object data="else/cleancode.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="800" height="1200" typemustmatch></object>
```

Comment: дай родителю `display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column`

Answer (score 0):

дай родителю

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуй

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.test{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

object{
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <video src="else/replicationDna.mp4" controls width="500" height="300"></video>
  <object data="else/cleancode.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="800" height="1200" typemustmatch></object>
</div>
```